# How do I fix a "Mismatched entity and/or field definitions" error on my configuration?

Tags: 8, entities, configuration

I'm getting the following error on my Drupal 8 configuration page.

> Entity/field definitions
> Mismatched entity and/or field definitions
> The following changes were detected in the entity type and field definitions.
>
> Content
> Update the node.rng_capacity field.
> Update the node.rng_registrants_duplicate field.
> Update the node.rng_registration_groups field.
> Update the node.rng_registration_type field.
> Update the node.rng_reply_to field.
> Update the node.rng_status field.

I'm not sure what caused these issues or how to go about resolving them. I think they may be leftover fragments/elements from when I deleted a registration or entity type.

Comment: The message shouldnt mean there isnt anything bad going on. Running `drush entity-updates` on your site should cancel these messages.

Comment: What else did you try? `drush updb`?

Comment: Hi, yes I tried both drush updb and drush entup. Entup would say success each time I ran it, but never seemed to update and it was there next time. Let me test the comments of the other answer - devel entity updates module. Thanks.

Comment: You should never use drush entup for core updates. Always use drush updb. If this fails it would be a major core issue. In this case restore from a backup and wait for a fix which shouldn't take long because it would affect a lot of installations.

Comment: Duly noted for the future thanks, Unfortunately I'd already ran Drush EntUp with the devel module installed but it seemed to sort the issue. Hopefully nothing that will later come back to bite me.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can solve this issue by two ways.

If you installed Drush, you can run `drush entity-updates`. Otherwise, add the following lines in the index.php file located in the Drupal root folder, before `$response->send();` and reload the page.

```php
try {
  \Drupal::entityDefinitionUpdateManager()->applyUpdates();
}
catch (EntityStorageException $e) {
  print_r($e);
}
```

Then remove the code from the *index.php* file.

Comment: Can you post drush comment warning or error here? So I can figure out what is the problem exactly.

Comment: I deleted my comment, the problem was with the PHP version my drush was using ( I had two versions, shell was using the old one, so drush was too). Thanks!

Comment: If anyone comes seeking this question how to change PHP version under which drush is running you can find this article helpful. <a href="http://www.fuelforbrain.com/how-change-php-version-drush-runs-under">How to change PHP version that drush runs under?</a>

Comment: I had this problem after updating from Drupal 8.3.2 to 8.3.3, but in my fields contained already data.

<blockquote>The SQL storage cannot change the schema for an existing field</blockquote>

Is there no simple way to update field storage and solve this mismatched entity error when there is already data in the fields?

Comment: Drush didn't work in my case for some reason, but I was able to use `drupal update:entities` instead.

Comment: applyUpdtes() does not exist anymore.
Error: Call to undefined method Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityDefinitionUpdateManager::applyUpdates() in main() (line 24 of index.php).

How can this be solved in Drupal 9?

Comment: This solution does not work with Drupal 9.

Comment: Yes. it's not working on D9.x

Answer (score 24):

**Solved!**

Method 1:
Go to the admin/reports/status and find the field machine name.

For Example: "paragraph.field_video_upload". Edit the field storage settings and save the configuration again. That's it.

It works.

[image]

(or)

Method 2:
If it's not working, please try the method below.

.install

```
<?php

/**
 * Implements hook_update_N().
 */
function HOOK_update_9001() {

  $entity_type_manager = \Drupal::entityTypeManager();
  $entity_type_manager->clearCachedDefinitions();

  $entity_type_ids = [];
  $change_summary = \Drupal::service('entity.definition_update_manager')->getChangeSummary();
  foreach ($change_summary as $entity_type_id => $change_list) {
    $entity_type = $entity_type_manager->getDefinition($entity_type_id);
    \Drupal::entityDefinitionUpdateManager()->installEntityType($entity_type);
    $entity_type_ids[] = $entity_type_id;
  }

  return t("Installed/Updated the entity type(s): @entity_type_ids", [
    '@entity_type_ids' => implode(', ', $entity_type_ids),
  ]);
}
```

RUN drush cim & drush cr

Comment: It makes the error go away, but I'm still not sure if it actually worked properly.

Comment: @colan it does, exporting the config make it clear.

Comment: I was going crazy searching how to insert my lost storage schema configurations for two fields, I had gone down to SqlContentEntityStorageSchema and I was trying to understand how to invoke its protected methods... and it was SO simple :D I wish I could upvote this answer many times :)

Comment: @colan, it depends on the underlying cause of the error. I have checked that the database, the field config and the field storage config are ok, and the only section that had been lost was the entity storage schema. It was missing for two fields (it can be checked looking at `\Drupal::keyValue('entity.storage_schema.sql')->get('node.field_schema_data.field_my_custom_field')`), and it was correctly restored after saving the field storage settings, so that was it – at least for me, YMMV.

Answer (score 18):

`drush entity-updates` (aka `drush entup`) has been [deprecated as of Drupal 8.7.0](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/releases/8.7.0). You either need to write an update script using hook_update_N(), or you can use the [Devel Entity Updates module](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel_entity_updates), which does the same thing as `drush entup` did previous to 8.7.0.

Comment: Many thanks Jaypan. First I've heard of this solution, but it worked perfectly. Installed the Devel Entity Updates Module you recommended and then ran drush entup again. This time it worked! I did vote up the answer, but because my rep is so low it's not display. Cheers

Comment: Thanks a lot, Jaypan. Working perfectly. Your answer is always helpful.

Comment: The "Devel Entity Updates" is not really suitable for a production release. Instructions for hook_update_N() can be found in https://www.drupal.org/node/3034742

Comment: the Devel Entity Updates module site says, "Do not use this to fix the Mismatched entity and/or field definitions error: again, this is not meant to fix production sites."

Comment: Another thing in Drupal that used to be a simple one-liner that now requires coding knowledge...

Comment: Not really, you can still use the devel entity updates module, and do the same thing. But this comes with risk, which is why they recommend a code-based solution. It was never able to be done without risk with the one-line, so nothing has changed.

Answer (score 11):

Find the field in /admin/reports/fields. For each entity that uses the field, edit the field and save the parameters again.

This should be updating the database and make the entity and the field match again.

Comment: This even works when the field in question is `layout_builder__layout` which is locked.

Comment: +1. This and answer by @thirsty six works.

Answer (score 6):

For Drupal 9, use [devel_entity_updates](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel_entity_updates) module

```
composer require 'drupal/devel_entity_updates'
drush en devel_entity_updates
drush entity-updates
```

should fix the issue.

Comment: This fixed it for me. I had to run: [drush entup] after installation.

Comment: While this may address the issue for some sites, it can't be used on production sites

Answer (score 4):

It is clearly written in the [Devel Entity Updates](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel_entity_updates):

**Do not use this to fix the Mismatched entity and/or field definitions error: again, this is not meant to fix production sites.**

This will not help these issues.

Here some links that could fix the issues:

https://www.drupal.org/project/paragraphs/issues/3062300
https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce/issues/2656896

Comment: Thank you.

this one fixed it for me https://www.drupal.org/node/3034742#comment-13999920

Answer (score 1):

For Drupal 8 and Drupal 9, there is the [Entity Update](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_update) module, which allows to update an entity schema with Drush or without it.

> The main objective of this module is to allow module developers and site administrators to update entity types schema even when entities have data.
> The update can be executed via Drush (recommended), from the web browser, or programmatically.
> The module also allows to view the list of entity types, the entity types update status, and show the content of an entity type.

Comment: I tried this and received the following `In SqlContentEntityStorageSchema.php line 1849:
                                                                                                  
  The SQL storage cannot change the schema for an existing field (uri in file entity) with data. `

Answer (score 0):

For Drupal 10 or Migrated from Drupal 9 to Drupal 10, or migrated Contrib modules like `Paragraph`

You need to add `devel_entity_updates`

```bash
$ drush composer require 'drupal/devel_entity_updates:^4.1'
```

Then Enable

And Run the Drush command

```bash
$ drush devel_entity_updates

The following updates are pending:

paragraph entity type : 
The paragraph.field_reusable_paragraph field needs to be updated.

 Do you wish to run all pending updates? (yes/no) [yes]:
 > yes

 [success] Finished performing updates.
```

This resolved the above issue

Comment: Warning: The devel_entity_updates module clearly states: 
"Do not use this to fix the Mismatched entity and/or field definitions error: again, this is not meant to fix production sites."

Answer (score 0):

You can Add **hook_update_N()** hook (in module_name.install file): to fix Mismatched entity and/or field definitions error for Configuration

```
/**
 * Update the Paragraph field definitions for mismatched fields.
 */
function hook_update_N() {
  try {

    $entityTypeManager = \Drupal::entityTypeManager();

    // Get the media entity type.
    $paragraphEntityType = $entityTypeManager->getDefinition('paragraph');

    // Install the media entity type to ensure field updates.
    \Drupal::entityDefinitionUpdateManager()->installEntityType($paragraphEntityType);

  }
  catch (\Exception $e) {
    watchdog_exception('logger_name', $e, 'hook_update_N failed');
  }
}
```

**Note:** I used nkf_update_8901() for hook_update_N(), where module_name : nkf, N denotes 8901

Follow [this](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Extension%21module.api.php/function/hook_update_N/9) document to read more about hook_update_N() hook

**I have used this approach** to fix a "Mismatched entity and/or field definitions" error for Configuration **due to couple of reasons**:

**In some projects :**

- Lower(dev) env can use "devel entity updates" but on higher(stg/prod) it is not recommended to use "devel entity updates" module.
  so in this particular scenario this approach hook_update_N() can be used
- It also helps to keep track of recent changes related to particular entity updates of db at code level

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code(on module_name.install file) to fix this mismatched entity issue. I tried this on Drupal 10 version. Please post your comment if you need any clarification on this.

```
/**
 *
 * Mismatched entity and/or field definitions Fix.
 */
function hook_update_N() {

  $entity_type_manager = \Drupal::entityTypeManager();
  $entity_type_manager->clearCachedDefinitions();
  $entity_type_ids = [];
  $change_summary = \Drupal::service('entity.definition_update_manager')->getChangeSummary();
  foreach ($change_summary as $entity_type_id => $change_list) {
    $entity_type = $entity_type_manager->getDefinition($entity_type_id);
    \Drupal::entityDefinitionUpdateManager()->installEntityType($entity_type);
    $entity_type_ids[] = $entity_type_id;
  }
  drupal_flush_all_caches();
  return t("Installed/Updated the entity type(s): @entity_type_ids", [
    '@entity_type_ids' => implode(', ', $entity_type_ids),
  ]);
}
```