# Correct analysis for "Mismatched entity and/or field definitions"

Tags: 8

Drupal 8 sometimes displays a warning in site status

> Mismatched entity and/or field definitions

There has already been [a question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/198628/im-getting-a-mismatched-entity-and-or-field-definitions-error-on-my-configura) about this and the answer is to run `drush entity-updates`.  I can't find any description of a solution directly from the GUI.

I have run the command several times and it works fine.  But I don't understand the point of Drupal printing this warning, rather than Drupal solving the problem automatically (by executing whatever the entity-updates command does).

Please can anyone tell me

1. Is there any analysis that I should do before running entity-updates?
2. Is there any reason I shouldn't write a cron hook that will call entity-updates automatically?
3. Should I raise an issue against Drupal core to request that Drupal runs the clean-up automatically rather than printing a warning?

Comment: _I don't understand the point of Drupal printing this warning, rather than Drupal solving the problem automatically_ Because it doesn't want to second-guess your development process. You've made changes to code, maybe you're not ready to run the updates yet, Drupal couldn't know. Just like when you create a database update, you have to run the updates for the code to execute. Automatic/inferred updating can be very dangerous for obvious reasons

Comment: See this discussion about `drush entity-updates` https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/221215/what-is-the-purpose-of-drush-entity-updates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to 4k4 and Clive and following the link I think I can now write up the answer to my question.

- This [Drupal Change Record](https://www.drupal.org/node/2554097) (and [more detail](https://www.drupal.org/node/2554101)) documents that
  module developers should write hook_update functions for entity updates. 
  So if you get the "mismatched" warning after a contrib module update
  then **it's a bug** in that module and you should not apply to update to the live site.
- This [question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/221215/what-is-the-purpose-of-drush-entity-updates) explains that entity-updates is a developer tool. 
  If you are a developer working on a test site you may see the
  "mismatched" warning whilst making changes.  You will run
  entity-updates when you are ready.

So the answer to my questions 2 and 3 is **no**.