# How to get rid of "The %field_name field needs to be uninstalled."

Tags: 8

I have a message in the `/admin/reports/status` page regarding some fields.

FYI, those are custom fields that I have deleted

Here is the message:

```
The %field_name field needs to be uninstalled.
```

To solve this, I ran cron, I `drush cr` and finally  `drush entup` =>but this last step display the following error:

```
In DiscoveryTrait.php line 52: The "field_item:mwd" plugin does not exist.
```

`mwd` is the id of custom field type for which there is a message in the status page...

Here is the Plugin definition and the Class definition of this custom field

```
 * @FieldType(
 *   id = "mwd",
 *   label = @Translation("Days of week in a Month for a user"),
 *   description = @Translation("Store all days of week in a month for a user."),
 *   category = @Translation("Calendar"),
 *   default_formatter = "mwd_ds_formatter",
 *   default_widget = "mwd_ds_widget",
 * )
 */
class MWDItem extends FieldItemBase implements FieldItemInterface{...
```

I have created an instance of this field type (with the GUI of drupal) and added it to a content type. This is this field which needs to be uninstalled if I conforms to the status page message.

Unfortunately I can't get rid of it: impossible to remove this warning in the /admin/reports/status page

Comment: The deleted field was a configured field?

Comment: I have updated my post to explain from where this field is coming from. If I understand well, this is a configured field as it has been created with the GUI of drupal and added to a content type.

Comment: Yes, this is a configured field. Normally it's no problem to delete a field from a content type. But in your case the delete process couldn't be completed because the field plugin is missing. I don't know how you managed to do this. There should be a warning when you try to uninstall a field module if it still has dependencies in config.

Comment: I have to say that the field plugin is not missing... I have added a bug issue there: https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3023054 I really don't know what to do.

Comment: The error message clearly says the plugin is missing. You can list all field type plugins with the Drupal Console command `drupal debug:plugin field.field_type`.

Comment: The plugin type which is missing is not a field type, but a typed data plugin. So check this, too: `drush ev "print_r(array_keys(\Drupal::typedDataManager()->getDefinitions()))"`

Comment: regarding `drupal debug`:  I have tried to install the console using `composer require drupal/console:~1.0 --prefer-dist --optimize-autoloader` but I got a problem `remove symfony/dom-crawler v4.2.1`. I am in D 8.6.4, I will first update in order to be able to install console

Comment: regarding `\Drupal::typedDataManager()->getDefinitions()`: I ran it, but no occurence of `mwd` in any of the resullted keys

Comment: For the field type plugins you can use Drush instead of Console: `drush ev "print_r(array_keys(\Drupal::service('plugin.manager.field.field_type')->getDefinitions()))"`.

Comment: regarding `\Drupal::service('plugin.manager.field.field_type')->getDefinitions()` : same thing: no occurence of mwd

Comment: OK, so the plugin manager can't discover the field type plugin class. Either because the module is disabled or the plugin code contains errors, you need more debugging until the plugin appears in getDefinitions().

Comment: Module is enabled (mwd field type is available), I also ran `drush dre mymodule; drush cr` and the apache log is completly empty... Problem arise when `drush entup => Accept to run pending update => The "field_item:mwd" plugin does not exist.`

Comment: I have deleted everything and started from an older db dump... Many thanks for your help!!! I assume something was corrupted in the DB

Comment: Yes, this is a good idea after a failed drush entup. You see now the field type in both plugin managers?

Comment: Yes I can see it in both... After a drush cr : nothing, but after using the "flush cache" menu of the devel module they both appear.

Comment: There is something wrong. I would test the custom field module in a fresh composer  based project (which includes the latest versions of Console and Drush) and check if it works there as it should.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a snippet which you could use in `hook_update` or `drush php` context. However it will only work if the tables are still there - while this is rare, it can happen - you're in this situation because something didn't happen correctly, so expect the unexpected.

```
$manager = \Drupal::entityDefinitionUpdateManager();
$definition = $manager->getFieldStorageDefinition("field_blah", "node");
$manager->uninstallFieldStorageDefinition($definition);
```

It the tables do not exist then the field cannot be programmatically uninstalled, as Drupal will try to query them. In this case, adding and removing the field through the UI is the easiest way, per other answers.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with a custom field. I solved it by **creating the broken field in the UI once again and deleting it afterwards:** The error went away.
Just take care of the name of the field (without the string "field_" at the beginning).

Comment: I had this after deleting some unwanted Paragraph Types. The [fixes that use `drush entup`](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/198628/how-do-i-fix-a-mismatched-entity-and-or-field-definitions-error-on-my-configur) all failed because the field had been deleted so the table in the database didn't exist. 

Creating another field of the same name in the same entity type e.g. a paragraph, and deleting it purges the message.